# Declaring a global variable outside a switch statement

Tags: c#

I would like to declare a global variable outside the switch statement where the resulting records could be from two different tables. How can I best achieve this?

```
var q;

Switch(petType)
{
case 1:
    var q = from c in Cats
                where c.Type equals == 1
                select c;
     break;
case 2:
    var q = from d in Dogs 
                where d.Type equals == 1
                select d; 
     break;
 }

foreach(var r in q)
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into polymorphism?

Comment: `Cats` and `Dogs` are two completely different types.  They can't be stored in the same variable.  C# is a statically typed language.

Comment: `Animal` - problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You have "var q" defined in 3 places. Only required in one place. Use object instead of var like below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Dog> Dogs = new List<Dog>();
            List<Cat> Cats = new List<Cat>();
            object q;
            int petType = 1;


            switch(petType)
            {
            case 1:
                q = from c in Cats
                            where c.Type == 1
                            select c;
                 break;
            case 2:
                q = from d in Dogs 
                            where d.Type == 1
                            select d; 
                 break;
             }

        }
    }

    public class Cat
    {
        public int Type { get; set; }
    }
    public class Dog
    {
        public int Type { get; set; }
    }

}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what @B.K. suggested, in case OP is still not clear.

```
public abstract class Animal {
   public int NoOfLegs { get; set; } // example
}

public class Cat : Animal {
}

public class Dog : Animal {
}

List<Animal> q;

Switch(petType)
{
   case 1:
   q = from c in Cats
       where c.Type equals == 1
       select c;
   break;

   case 2:
   q = from d in Dogs 
       where d.Type equals == 1
       select d; 
   break;
}

foreach(var r in q)
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```